# How to apt install python-pybind11?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt, pybind11

I see form my project document that I need to install `python-pybind11` by using

```
sudo apt -y install python-pybind11
```

but I got error like this:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package python-pybind11

I'm not sure if `python-pybind11` is a valid package, where can I check it?

Comment: Welcome , the `python-pybind11` is a valid package for Ubuntu 18.04 and higher.

Comment: @Felix Xu, You should accept correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use this to install pybind11:**

```
pip install pybind11
```

Refer from [Here](https://pypi.org/project/pybind11/).

Comment: after I run the comand, I got: `Collecting pybind11
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/7c/e71995e59e108799800cb0fce6c4b4927914d7eada0723dd20bae3b51786/pybind11-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 13kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pybind11
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybind11'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
`

Comment: @FeilixXu, Seems to be a permission issue. Run this with “sudo”.

Comment: now another error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
`. I'm using ubuntu16, is that related?

Comment: Peanut gallery comment: Please don't `sudo pip install`! Consider `pip install --user`, but really, just try using a `virtualenv`!

Answer (score 7):

In some systems, you may need

```
sudo apt -y install python3-pybind11
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 18.04

```
apt-get install python-pybind11
```

On Mac,

```
brew install pybind11
```

In Ubuntu 16.04, you'll need to install yourself. One way is as follows:

```
# Some prerequisites (but not all of them)
apt-get install cmake
pip3 install pytest

# Clone, build and install 
git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git 
cd pybind11 
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake .. 
make install
```

[Reference](https://kezunlin.me/post/a41adc1/)

Comment: I used your instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59938992/4999991)

Answer (score 0):

### OS Way

`dnf --enablerepo=crb -y install pybind11-devel`

or

`yum install pybind11`

Pybind installation docs: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html

### Pip way

`pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade`