# pybind11 running the test cases

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, pybind11

I'm trying to learn `pybind11` and the first Google result is [this page](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html), where you should be guided towards compiling and running some test cases. From [this page](https://pypi.org/project/pybind11/), I have installed `bybind11` by:

```
pip3 install pybind11
```

and I have installed:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev cmake
```

as instructed in [the original page](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html). But I don't know how to go to the next step which is to

```
mkdir build ...
```

and the rest of the steps to compile the test cases. I suppose this should be inside the `pybind11` installation folder installed via `pip3`.

my environment is:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS bionic
- Python3 3.6.9
- pip 20.0.2

and my questions are:

- where is the path to the presumed test cases where I can follow the rest of [the tutorial](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html) from
- is this the correct/best way to install pybind11? if not what is the recommended method of installation?

**P.S.1.** using `pip3 show pybind11` I realized that I have version `2.4.3` installed and the installation folder is `/usr/<userName>/.local/lib/python3.6/sitepackages`. However, inside the `pybind11` folder there are no test cases as far as I can see.

**P.S.2.** From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56552686/4999991) I installed via `sudo apt install python-pybind11` and [from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/54434/535800) using `dpkg --listfiles python-pybind11` I found the installation folder at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Not only there are no test cases in this folder either, but this is also python2.7 which I don't want to use!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install `pybind11` as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56552686/4999991) by cloning the GitHub repository:

```sh
python3 -m pip install pytest numpy scipy
sudo apt install -y cmake python3-dev libeigen3-dev libboost-dev git
git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git
cd pybind11
cmake -DDOWNLOAD_CATCH=1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install
cd ..
```

Then you can run the tests by going to the folder `cd tests`. Next, follow steps in the tutorial, starting with `mkdir build`.

**P.S.** You may also need to make sure your Python packages are up to date, following the instructions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/euvqdt/installing_python3_and_pip_on_minimal_ubuntu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Comment: this is the correct answer. thanks. but I think you need to install it first as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56552686/4999991).

Comment: It should be possible to build and run the tests after installing the prerequisites like `cmake` and `pytest`.  In order to build the tests in the repository, it should not be necessary to install `pybind11` itself using a package manager.

Comment: I applied some edits, but they are implemented anyway. I hope you are ok with them?

Comment: You don't need to run the tests from within the `tests` directory. You don't even need to install pybind11 to run the tests. After `cmake ..` in the bit of code in this answer, run `make` to build (add `-j` for speed), and then `make check` to run the tests.